# Is the Namespace for a SOAP Web Service case sensitive?

Tags: .net, web-services

I tried deploying a web service that I changed to a machine and when I tested out one of the web methods I got an error stating

"Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header Soapaction"

I did some searching for the issue and that error seems to occur at times when there is a difference in namespace. I looked at what is working in my development environment and the namespace looks somewhat like this

`https://webservice/ServiceName`

and the namespace for the previous web service in production looks like this

`https://webservice/servicename`

Does case matter? Should they match exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should match exactly: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NSNameComparison/

> The URI references below are all
>   different for the purposes of
>   identifying namespaces, since they
>   differ in case:
>
> •http://www.example.org/wine
>
> •http://www.Example.org/wine
>
> •http://www.example.org/Wine

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Everything in XML is case sensitive.

Comment: I would think that would be true for tag names, not attribute values. I'll try changing it and see if it works.

Comment: I think you're right - because it's a URI and URIs are case-sensitive - but the SOAPAction header is actually passed on the HTTP request and not in the XML. (Actually maybe I'm out of date - 1.2 doesn't have SOAPAction.)

Comment: Namespaces aren't just attribute values.  They're part of the markup.  All XML markup is case-sensitive.