# AX 2012 ContractFilter mismatch

Tags: wcf, biztalk, ax

I'm following the Microsoft document "Using Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 to exchange documents with Microsoft Dynamics AX_AX2012.pdf". I have the sample XML order create collected by BizTalk, transformed and passed onto AX, this is being collected by an AX inbound port but then I get the following error:

*The request failed with the following error:  The message with Action 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/Create' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).*

I'm new to AX and don't know how best to troubleshoot this. How could I find the WSDL that describes the SalesOrderService/Create operation? Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Dynamix AX, but this is quite a common error when any of the issues described in the error message occur.

On the Send Port you've created in BizTalk, ensure that:

- Note also that [Soap Actions are case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118001/is-the-namespace-for-a-soap-web-service-case-sensitive) (i.e. /create not /Create)
- WS-NetTcp as the type (you can also try WCF-Custom with the NetTcp Binding - Configure - Tab #2)
- In the "Configure" tab, the Address URL at the top (seems to be correct). Note the point about Port 8201
- The below textarea needs to set the SOAP Action to http://schemas.microsoft.com/Microsoft Dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/read

If this doesn't work, you might see if there is anyway to get Dynamix AX to expose its services using basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding - this way, it would be much easier to debug the communication using a tool like Fiddler.

Re : How do you see the Mex / WSDL to work?
Hopefully AX has an http-get enabled mex endpoint for the net.tcp endpoint. See [WCF NetTcpBinding with mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130366/wcf-nettcpbinding-with-mex)

Comment: It is possible to make synchronous exchange with AX using various WCF bindings. However, this is deemed less efficient (from an AX perspective) when exchange large volumes of data - hence why I would like to prove the asynch comms via the file adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look on http://www.axaptapedia.com/Webservice.

You do not mention your AX version but [Consuming Web Services in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4462) or [for AX 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24742) may be relevant to you.

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics AX_AX2012.pdf